# laravel 5 - 403 error on form post

Tags: php, forms, laravel, post, http-status-code-403

Good stack over flow people,

The following generic form is failing to post correctly, returns a 403 forbidden error.

however when one removes random chunks of text from the `value=` field it can post.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://domain.com/generic" accept-charset="UTF-8">

<input type="hidden" name="items" value="[{&quot;sku&quot;:&quot;ttwvslyvjblc&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;5 on 5 - 1 hour indoor (Loose Cannons)&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:14,&quot;quantity&quot;:1,&quot;detail&quot;:{&quot;utc_offset&quot;:36000000,&quot;venue&quot;:{&quot;country&quot;:&quot;au&quot;,&quot;localized_country_name&quot;:&quot;Australia&quot;,&quot;city&quot;:&quot;Kensington&quot;,&quot;address_1&quot;:&quot;Corner of Kensington Road and Altona Street&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;YMCA Kensington Community Recreation Centre &quot;,&quot;lon&quot;:144.924556,&quot;id&quot;:1412922,&quot;lat&quot;:-37.795941,&quot;repinned&quot;:false},&quot;rsvp_limit&quot;:14,&quot;headcount&quot;:0,&quot;visibility&quot;:&quot;public_limited&quot;,&quot;waitlist_count&quot;:0,&quot;created&quot;:1461736046000,&quot;fee&quot;:{&quot;amount&quot;:14,&quot;accepts&quot;:&quot;paypal&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;per person&quot;,&quot;currency&quot;:&quot;AUD&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Price&quot;,&quot;required&quot;:&quot;1&quot;},&quot;maybe_rsvp_count&quot;:0,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;<p>*Please note that this session is for advanced players only with the title Loose Cannons*</p> <p>Each week we play a friendly competitive game of basketball. There is a half time break of 2 mins where teams have the chance to discuss strategies. We have a 4 minute substitution which is notified with a whistle. Maximise your fitness each game while we pump some tunes!</p> <p>Points are totalled and the team with the most wins.</p> <p>Some of our members are casual, while many are regular, this creates a dynamic mix of friends and new faces, this <a href=\&quot;http://www.basketball613.com.au/code-of-conduct/\&quot;>culture</a> is what separates Basketball613 apart from standard league competition basketball.</p> <p>The rules are refereed by the players, for the players. We use the FIBA rule system.</p> <p>Coloured sashes are provided to players to identify which team you'r on, so you just need to bring comfortable clothes.</p> <p>If you are attending a game for the first time, you will be allocated to the Intermediate/beginners session to start of with. We will then assess and allocate you to the appropriate skill level game after your first game. To find out which group you have been allocated to, please view your profile title before you book in your next session. When you arrive ask reception where the basketball courts are.</p> <p>Payment is made online, preferably 1 week in advance.</p> <p>Facilities: Showers, Parking, Trains, Drinking Water.</p>&quot;,&quot;how_to_find_us&quot;:&quot;When you arrive ask reception where the basketball courts are.&quot;,&quot;event_url&quot;:&quot;http://www.meetup.com/basketball613/events/231502076/&quot;,&quot;yes_rsvp_count&quot;:6,&quot;duration&quot;:3600000,&quot;announced&quot;:false,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;5 on 5 - 1 hour indoor (Loose Cannons)&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;ttwvslyvjblc&quot;,&quot;time&quot;:1467104400000,&quot;updated&quot;:1461817693000,&quot;group&quot;:{&quot;join_mode&quot;:&quot;open&quot;,&quot;created&quot;:1358743637000,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Melbourne Basketball 613&quot;,&quot;group_lon&quot;:144.96000671387,&quot;id&quot;:6760582,&quot;urlname&quot;:&quot;basketball613&quot;,&quot;group_lat&quot;:-37.810001373291,&quot;who&quot;:&quot;Ballers&quot;},&quot;status&quot;:&quot;upcoming&quot;,&quot;numspotsleft&quot;:8,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://api.basketball613.com.au/members-area/event/ttwvslyvjblc&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:{&quot;date_usa&quot;:&quot;06-28-2016&quot;,&quot;date_aus&quot;:&quot;28-06-2016&quot;,&quot;time&quot;:&quot;07:00pm&quot;,&quot;day&quot;:&quot;28&quot;,&quot;monthname&quot;:&quot;Jun&quot;,&quot;dayname&quot;:&quot;Tuesday&quot;},&quot;quantity&quot;:1}}]">           
<input class="btn btn-flat btn-success" type="submit" value="Checkout to play!">  
</form>
```

the route works:

```
Route::post('/generic', function() {
        dd('ok!');
});
```

Note: i have disabled csrf to isolate the issue.

Why am i unable to recieve the posted the input items?

Why is this creating a `403 Forbidden Access to this resource on the server is denied!`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue on the server.

mod_security had updated at some point and the domain needed to be whitelisted.

Comment: Could you please show me how to whitelisted my domain because I got this error too. I'm using shared hosting cPanel.

Comment: Yes, I got this error too. In xamp ins word! but when I public to shared hosting is error 403 with request value is code html. Like youtube embed code is error but plaint text is ok, So how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

for your route :

```
 route::post('generic',['as' => 'generic'],function() {


});
```

your form code :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('generic')}}" accept-charset="UTF-8">

<input type="hidden" name="items" value="your value">           
<input class="btn btn-flat btn-success" type="submit" value="Checkout to play!">  
</form>
```

I hope that can help you

Comment: no the routes work, the form works, it's something to do with the input

Comment: ok try <?php echo 'youValue' ?> in the value attribute of your hidden input

Comment: I cant because i get a 403 directly after clicking the button. Funny thing is it works on my development(homestead) but not production.

Comment: Lol , ok can you copy and past all error message content ?

Comment: 403
Forbidden

Access to this resource on the server is denied!

Comment: You need to check /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log for reason why. because it's not a laravel Error , it's a server Restriction.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use YouTube video embed code. It is not the best solution but it will solve the problem. The server accepts simple strings but not HTML codes, so in your form submit the video identifier from YouTube like `VQKMoT-6XSg` in `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQKMoT-6XSg` and on your controller add the whole YouTube embed markup.

```
$videoIdentifier = $_POST['video_identifier']; // or get it via FormRequest
```

Here is the function to return the full markup.

```
function getEmbedCode($videoIdentifier, $title = null){
    return "<iframe width='1022' height='500' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/{$videoIdentifier}' title='{$title}' frameborder='0' allow='accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
}
```

Then store the entire markup in DB:

```
$data = [
   'filed1' => 'value',
   'filed2' => 'value',
   'embed_code' => getEmbedCode($getEmbedCode)
]; 

// store the data array into DB

YouModel::create($data);
```